# ImportError with gevent and requests async module

Tags: python, concurrency, gevent

I'm writing a simple script that:

1. Loads a big list of URLs
2. Get the content of each URL making concurrent HTTP requests using [requests' async](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests) module
3. Parses the content of the page with lxml in order to check if a link is in the page
4. If the link is present on the page, saves some info about the page in a ZODB database

When I test the script with 4 or 5 URLs It works well, I only have the following message when the script ends:

```
 Exception KeyError: KeyError(45989520,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

But when I try to check about 24000 URLs it fails toward the end of the list (when there are about 400 URLs left to check) with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "/home/alex/code/.virtualenvs/linka/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/async.py", line 83, in map
  File "/home/alex/code/.virtualenvs/linka/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent-1.0b2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/greenlet.py", line 405, in joinall
ImportError: No module named queue
Exception KeyError: KeyError(45989520,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

I tried both with the version of gevent available on [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent) and downloading and installing the latest version (1.0b2) from [gevent repository](http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/list).

I cannot understand why this happened, and why it happened only when I check a bunch of URLs. Any suggestions?

Here is the entire script:

```
from requests import async, defaults
from lxml import html
from urlparse import urlsplit
from gevent import monkey
from BeautifulSoup import UnicodeDammit
from ZODB.FileStorage import FileStorage
from ZODB.DB import DB
import transaction
import persistent
import random

storage = FileStorage('Data.fs')
db = DB(storage)
connection = db.open()
root = connection.root()
monkey.patch_all()
defaults.defaults['base_headers']['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
defaults.defaults['max_retries'] = 10


def save_data(source, target, anchor):
    root[source] = persistent.mapping.PersistentMapping(dict(target=target, anchor=anchor))
    transaction.commit()


def decode_html(html_string):
    converted = UnicodeDammit(html_string, isHTML=True)
    if not converted.unicode:
        raise UnicodeDecodeError(
            "Failed to detect encoding, tried [%s]",
            ', '.join(converted.triedEncodings))
    # print converted.originalEncoding
    return converted.unicode


def find_link(html_doc, url):
    decoded = decode_html(html_doc)
    doc = html.document_fromstring(decoded.encode('utf-8'))
    for element, attribute, link, pos in doc.iterlinks():
        if attribute == "href" and link.startswith('http'):
            netloc = urlsplit(link).netloc
            if "example.org" in netloc:
                return (url, link, element.text_content().strip())
    else:
        return False


def check(response):
    if response.status_code == 200:
        html_doc = response.content
        result = find_link(html_doc, response.url)
        if result:
            source, target, anchor = result
            # print "Source: %s" % source
            # print "Target: %s" % target
            # print "Anchor: %s" % anchor
            # print
            save_data(source, target, anchor)
    global todo
    todo = todo -1
    print todo

def load_urls(fname):
    with open(fname) as fh:
        urls = set([url.strip() for url in fh.readlines()])
        urls = list(urls)
        random.shuffle(urls)
        return urls

if __name__ == "__main__":

    urls = load_urls('urls.txt')
    rs = []
    todo = len(urls)
    print "Ready to analyze %s pages" % len(urls)
    for url in urls:
        rs.append(async.get(url, hooks=dict(response=check), timeout=10.0))
    responses = async.map(rs, size=100)
    print "DONE."
```

Comment: Have you tried some debuging to get more information on the script's state when it fails? Is it always the same url? (catch exception and log url) Is it a memory issue? (look at memory usage during execution)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the source of your problem, but why do you have monkey.patch_all() not at the top of the file?

Could you try putting

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
```

at the top of your main program and see if it fixes anything?

Comment: I think that monkey patching is not needed at all, because monkey patching is done internally by the `async` module. BTW I followed your suggestion and the same exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

I am such a big n00b but anyway, I can try ... !
I guess you can try to change your import list by this one :

```
from requests import async, defaults
import requests
from lxml import html
from urlparse import urlsplit
from gevent import monkey
import gevent
from BeautifulSoup import UnicodeDammit
from ZODB.FileStorage import FileStorage
from ZODB.DB import DB
import transaction
import persistent
import random
```

Try this and tell me if it works .. I guess that can solve your problem :)

Comment: And if the problem is still there after trying my solution, maybe this link can help : http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/251918/import-queue-dont-exist

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. But why do you think this will solve my problem?

Comment: 'Cause I had the same problem and It worked for me. I still don't understand why ... but anyway, It's free to test :-)

Answer (score 0):

good day.
I think it's open python bug with number Issue1596321
http://bugs.python.org/issue1596321